# how Facebook taggable_friends permission work in facebook sdk 2.2

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to understand new taggable_friends permission added in facebook sdk works?
i am getting all friends list in previous Facebook sdk ,
but in new Facebook sdk its not allowed only those friends will display who are using this app,
is there any way to get all friends list ?
what taggable_friends do ,can i get all list by using this permission?

```
/{user-id}/taggable_friends
new Request(
    session,
    "/me/taggable_friends",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Taggable_friends are for tagging people. If you are not tagging people you can not use it. You can not use it to get all friends. And there is no way to get all friends

Comment: i am getting this error
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 10
  }
}
i graph explorer 
when this will gives friends list ?

Comment: The error message is correct. If you are going to use that on people that are not admins, developers or testers you need to submit your app to Facebook and get it approved. They will check that you are only using it for tagging people

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
means when i post something via app then it will give list of friends for tagging ,without submit any post i can't get all lists of friends ,is it right ?

Comment: It can only be used for tagging so of course you need to call it before you post. How else would you tag someone

Comment: yeah but my requirement is to get all friends list and showing in listview ,so i want to know can i get all friends list by using taggable_friends and without posting something on facebook .

Comment: How would you tag someone if you don't post?

Comment: i know i am just finding a way to get friends list 
if you have some idea to get all friends in a app via facbook 
please share.